# Update multiple rows from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update multiple rows from one table to another table.

I have this that works but I need to update 8 values in one query instead of 8 separate queries.

I need this

```
slot_id  |  spell_id
--------------------
0    |  1518
1    |  1519
2    |  1522
3    |  3476
4    |  4881
6    |  3475
7    |  4880
```

to this

```
spell1 | spell2 | spell3 | spell4 | spell5 | spell6 | spell7 | spell8
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   0   |   0    |   0    |    0   |   0    |     0  |   0    |    0
```

What I have accomplished is 1 at a time.

```
UPDATE instance_saved_info
INNER JOIN character_memmed_spells ON instance_saved_info.id = character_memmed_spells.id
SET instance_saved_info.Spell1 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 0
```

What I need to add in to make it work is this.

```
SET instance_saved_info.Spell2 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 1
SET instance_saved_info.Spell3 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 2
SET instance_saved_info.Spell4 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 3
SET instance_saved_info.Spell5 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 4
SET instance_saved_info.Spell6 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 5
SET instance_saved_info.Spell7 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 6
SET instance_saved_info.Spell8 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 7
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well you can declare multiple `SET` operator like

```
UPDATE instance_saved_info
INNER JOIN character_memmed_spells 
ON instance_saved_info.id = character_memmed_spells.id
SET instance_saved_info.Spell1 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id,
instance_saved_info.Spell2 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id2,
.....
WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 0
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what the OP is asking.  The `where` criteria changes for each field being updated if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @sgeddes, may be but didn't OP said *but I need to update 8 values in one query...*?

Comment: That didn't work, I'm still teaching myself sql, Let me try to explain better. The SET part will work but the WHERE clause needs to be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 as well. so

    `SET instance_saved_info.Spell1 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id
    WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 0

    SET instance_saved_info.Spell2 = character_memmed_spells.spell_id1
    WHERE character_memmed_spells.slot_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use a subquery with  `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` the 8 fields you need to `update`:

```
UPDATE instance_saved_info i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, 
           max(case when slot_id = 0 then spell_id end) slot0,
           max(case when slot_id = 1 then spell_id end) slot1,
           ....
           max(case when slot_id = 7 then spell_id end) slot7
    FROM character_memmed_spells 
    GROUP BY id) c ON i.id = c.id
SET i.Spell1 = c.slot0, i.Spell2 = c.slot1, ..., i.Spell8 = c.slot7
```

Comment: I tried that and it only effected 1 row instead of all 8

Comment: @conFIGuredAPK -- I think you need to post sample data and desired results.  As I understood the question, you wanted to update 8 columns in a single row, not 8 different rows in a table.

Comment: updated my question with better understanding, I do not know how to post my tables though to show example.

Comment: @conFIGuredAPK -- same issue, still need table structures (and preferably sample data and desired results).  Are you updating 1 row in a table or 8 rows in table?  Columns or Rows?

Comment: updated question, hope that helps more to understand.